# Automatically inserting text into bash case statement with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have been stumped with a problem that I am currently trying to figure out.  I have a file containing a bash case statement similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# some stuff here
case "$1" in
  start)
    # some more stuff here
    ;;
  stop|restart)
    # here is some more stuff
    ;;
  *)
    # stuff stuff stuff
    ;;
esac
```

I wanted to (with a script) insert some commands at the end of the first case statement using `sed`.  So far, I have come up with the following:

```
sed -e '/^[ \t]*start)/,$ { s/^\([ \t]*\);;/\1my_command_here\n\1;;/ }'
```

It will insert the commands into ALL of the case statements, and I can't seem to have it match on only the first statement.  Here is what I want the `sed` command to output:

```
#!/bin/bash
# some stuff here
case "$1" in
  start)
    # some more stuff here
    my_command_here
    ;;
  stop|restart)
    # here is some more stuff
    ;;
  *)
    # stuff stuff stuff
    ;;
esac
```

I was originally going to non-greedy glob from `start)` to the first `;;` but I couldn't seem to get that working either. Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't `awk` be better in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't choose your input file, you can solve it as described:

```
sed -e '/^ *start) *$/ { :b; N; s/\( *\);;/\1my_command_here\n&/; te; bb; }; :e'
```

1. Find `start)`.
2. Read and append lines until we find a `;;` to replace.
3. Replace it with your command followed by itself

However, if you are writing this script and want to be able to automatically insert commands to run on start, you should create a directory and source all files in it at the point you want.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick!  I will have to look into some of those modifiers you used.

Comment: Make sure that these modifiers do exist in other sed variants (e.g. BSD sed), if you need portability

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
awk '
   BEGIN { in_start = 0; }
   $1 == "start)" { in_start = 1; }
   $1 == ";;" && in_start == 1 { printf "some_command;\n"; in_start = 0; }
   { print; }
' <your.init>
```

Likely, text processing of any level of complexity can be done with bare `sed`. But not any should :)